# Highlight the text in PDF

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pdf.js

```
<script>
    var pdfPath = "@Url.Content(ViewBag.ProcessedPdfPath)";

    function searchAndHighlight() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchText').value;

        pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath).promise.then(function (pdfDoc_) {
            pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
            for (var pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdfDoc.numPages; pageNum++) {
                pdfDoc.getPage(pageNum).then(function (page) {
                    page.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {
                        textContent.items.forEach(function (textItem) {
                            if (textItem.str.includes(searchText)) {
                                var highlightDiv = document.createElement('div');
                                highlightDiv.className = 'highlight';
                                highlightDiv.style.left = textItem.transform[4]+10 + 'px';
                                highlightDiv.style.top = textItem.transform[5] - 10 + 'px';
                                highlightDiv.style.width = textItem.width + 'px';
                                highlightDiv.style.height = textItem.height + 'px';
                                document.getElementById('pageContainer').appendChild(highlightDiv);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The highlighting was occurring beneath the PDF, the positioning was incorrect.I want to search and highlight the text in the PDF.